Failed update to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Yes, I am one of those fools who pressed « yes » upon being asked whether I wanted to update from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. At least I waited until getting home from travel, knowing there was a small possibility things could go wrong.
First order of business: no, I didn’t back up first, and yes, thank goodness, I can find my home directory from the terminal and access my data - I just tarballed everything important.
Problem is, it seems I cannot mount anything in USB - whether it is USB keys or an external hard drive. Of course I can’t get WiFi either ( or a graphical interface for that matter).
What to do?
I can add some literal screenshots (as in, taken with my phone) in case they help.

This question is similar to: Failed update to 24.04. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

For most users, the release-upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 was problem-free. You were wise to be prepared for the rare eventuality that you encountered.

Make a new 24.04 LiveUSB on a different machine, test your hardware in the "Try Ubuntu" environment. If you hardware works, then reinstall.

Yes, that is what I started to do. I'm happily backing up before reinstalling. Now, if I choose to reinstall erasing the previous system, will I be just erasing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, or will I also be erasing my data (which, again, I'm backing up, but an elephant might drop from the ceiling and crush my USB key)?

The default is to format (complete erasure). If you know how, you can limit the erasure and retain existing data. But don't count on that: Any mistake or typo, and....

Yup, erased the data (no warning given), and recovered it from the backup. Now, though - wouldn't it be a very good idea to have a separate partition for the /home directory? Why is that not the default or a recommended option, as it was (if memory serves me right) in the days of old? (I'm tempted to reinstall everything just to do that.)
